# error when running python on terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I get this error when i try to run python in my terminal

```
-bash: /Users/steve/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

I originally had Anaconda installed and then accidentally also installed Canopy.  This caused a problem in that every time I tried to install a package (like beautifulsoup) it said it was already installed, saying 'requirement satisfied' (b/c of anaconda).  when i tried to run it on python it would say it wasn't installed (b/c of canopy).  so i followed the instructions to uninstall canopy and the above message still comes up. Not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have an old link to your non-existent canopy.

Comment: how can i change it/point it at anaconda?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your python command is using a link which is pointing to the non-existent file `/Users/rkauf/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python`.

You want to change your link to point to a valid python installation. If it's located in `/usr/bin/python` (check with e.g. `which python`), the command is along the lines of:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python # remove the old link. the -f option for ln also works
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python # create a new link
```

**OBS**: Always use `sudo` with caution. The first command removes a file, and it cannot be undone.